# Django - Manipulating Data Posted from a form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a Django form all working fine, however I need to update one filed after the user has posted the form, I was thinking this should be done in the view? My code is below for the view definition in question.

```
def edit_change(request, change_id):
change = get_object_or_404(Change, id=int(change_id))
form = ChangeForm(request.POST or None, instance=change)
change_id = Change.objects.get(id=int(change_id))

context = dict(change=change, id=change_id,form=form)



if form.is_valid():
    if form['change_id'] = ""
        form.['change_id'] = "TEST_NUM"

    cmodel = form.save()


    cmodel.save()
    return redirect(changes)

return render_to_response('editchange.html',context,   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Basically I want to see if the change_id has a value, if not add a value (date + (number of changes for that day + 1)), the continue to save the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def edit_change(request, change_id):

    ............

    if form.is_valid():
        change_id = form.cleaned_data['change_id']

        cmodel = form.save()

        if not change_id:
            cmodel.change_id = "TEST_NUM"
            cmodel.save()
        return redirect(changes)

    return render_to_response('editchange.html',context,   context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `form.is_valid()`, you create a `form.data` dict which `form.save()` then passes into the `model` associated with the `form`. If you add the in-between step of `model_object = form.save(commit=False)`, you create a model instance, populated with all the `form.data` values. You can change and save this model instance as you need. E.g. `model_object.change_id = "TEST_NUM"`. When you are done, you can finish with `model_object.save()`, never having need to use `form.save()`

More detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982699/django-using-savecommit-false-to-add-user-id-to-a-form-dont-modify-save-or

Answer (score 0):

I would redefine the clean method of the form, so that it makes the modification in the cleaned_data dict.